# How to insert a map into another map?

Tags: leaflet, map-service

If you look [at this site](http://www.meda.org/what-we-do/meda-around-the-world) it has a main map window but it also has a small window map at the top right corner.

1. What is the technical term for the smaller window?
2. How is that window created?

I am currently using leaflet js and I wanted to insert that [into my map here](http://disignt.com/teddy/jordan/).

Comment: the technical term is an "overview map"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is an overview map. There is a plugin for leaflet that provides this functionality that cab be found here : https://github.com/areichman/leaflet-overview

Comment: This is great...That's what I was looking for.