# Overview map for Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, map-overviews

I am looking for an **overview map** functionality for Leaflet. A participant at a conference was quite convinced that this is part of the Leaflet API - unfortunately I don't remember his name so I cannot ask him where to look for that.

The only overview map functionality for Leaflet I was able to find is 
[this code](https://github.com/areichman/leaflet-overview) on github (also mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110594) on gis.stackexchange).

Assuming that an overview map is a rather commonly used feature and taking the low github popularity of 4 stars into account, I am wondering if there is a more popular solution.

Is an overview map funtionality included in the Leaflet API? Or is there another solution besides [the aforementioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110594)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Leaflet.MiniMap plugin](https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap) (listed on the [plugins page](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#minimaps--synced-maps))